# How do I create dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
The program I should create will use a dynamic array which will store Revenue objects.  The array should be dynamic so that the user of the program can enter the number of Revenue records. I am confused as to how to pull this off.
```

Thanks

for example say i have a:

```
class Revenue
{
private:
(tons of function members in middle)

public:

}
```

Now I need to make an array that looks something like this

int arry;

```
cout << "how many Revenue tiers do you want?: "; cin >> arry;
Revenue rev[arry];//dynamic array
```

(this is wrong to do of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
Revenue* rev = new Revenue[arry];
```

And when you're done with it, do not forget to delete it

```
delete[] rev;
```

It is much better though to use smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`), although for arrays `std::shared_ptr` is a bit trickier to use as you have to define your own deallocator.

With `std::unique_ptr` you can write your code like

```
std::unique_ptr<Revenue[]> p(new Revenue[arry]);
```

and forget about destruction, deletion etc. The smart pointer will take care all cleanup when it goes out of scope.

Comment: it said it expected a type specifier but other than that your info worked thanks.

Comment: very cool i would use your technique but unfortunately it is required that i use a dynamic array. anyway what could be causing this type specifier and what does this mean?

Comment: @LegacyWink just refresh the page, the line should be `Revenue* rev = new Revenue[arry];` instead of `Revenue* rev = new rev[arry];`

Comment: @LegacyWink the array name is `rev`, the right hand side `new Revenue[arry]` tells the compiler to allocate memory for `arry` elements of type `Revenue`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use dynamic allocation/deallocation *manually* , instead

Use [*`std::vector`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
std::vector < Revenue > vec;

cin >> arry;

vec.resize( arry ); // Resizes vec to hold exactly arry no. of objects
```